# Handling spread of a union of tuples in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript project where I have a function that takes two arguments, one of which is a number and the other is either a number or a string:

```js
function test(num: number, numOrText: number | string) { /* ... */ }
```

I can call this function and spread the parameters from a predefined tuple:

```js
const p1: [number, string] = [42, 'test']
const p2: [number, number] = [42, 3.14]

test(...p1)
test(...p2)
```

But if I try to do the same with a union of these tuples, I get an error: `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter`.

```js
const p3: [number, string] | [number, number] = createParams()
test(...p3)
// Error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

[Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCjOAXInAWwCMUAnAGgJEIHkyAVFADynyNLMQB9EMyYYAOYBKAN4BfAFBSICDIgAOARnwBtDuSr9BQgLqIAvIjUAWAExUA5KgxW9s%20VCXn1mytRLkDxs5cQAzAB0yqYOUrZYQdEqIhHoUTHmcTKgkLAIiBBkKACGqAAKuWS5hGiYIm40nNpQAsIGvBrVWp6cBmKIOVAgZEgqiNJyYAqKAVVeHjoNPCbuVO4%20WTn5KEUlZRXxGJjRQWNxAPSHiACiZGRwZPgAgnyKKwAmiMVCNChgzoQgCigwUAALciIAG5ABuKBeyBAigANpCoABPRSQq6IUhKXJoNAoZ5QOBQnKjYqlFCoMhSIA)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `createParams` is of type `[number, string] | [number, number]`

This can be assigned to type `[number, string | number]`, which is a tuple.

```ts
function createParams(): [number, string] | [number, number] { return p1; }
const p3: [number, string | number] = createParams();
test(...p3);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCjCAtgLkR1wCMUAnAGiLwHlyAVFADykOLPMQB9ENyYYAOYBKAN4AoRNMQQEaOABsUAOkVwh2PNWL0mrEQG4JAXwkS5YDIgAOARkIBtDhWr9BQgLqIAvIkcALABM1ADkqBihnhbyULZBTi5UNKQU3n6BIYgAzCp2AdESEVgqpfYiReglZUEV5qCQsAiy5CgAhqgACm3kbbhomCKJeJxuUALC3rzOI64pnN5iiK1QIORI9oaIZpbWNtnDqcnuwjzzab4t7V09fQNGlRiYpSr7DxJAA)